# Formula for calculating sliding friction

Tags: forces, friction, drag

What is the formula for calculating frictional force of a sliding body?
I have already tried $F=UR$ but it is not working.

Comment: what are $F,U,R$? A sliding body is causing friction on something else or a body is experiencing sliding friction?

Answer (score 0):

$F=\mu R$ gives the maximum static friction that can occur before a body slips, then sliding friction occurs and that's usually lower than the maximum static friction.

The value of it will vary depending on the substances involved, but can be determined experimentally like this:

Drag the body along at constant speed using a force meter and monitor the readings, do an average over time.